# Do I commit symfony jwt private and public key files?

Tags: symfony, jwt

Sorry for the rooky question. I am implementing jwt authentication in symfony 6 with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. I generated 2 key files using this command

```
php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair
```

And config/jwt/private.pem and config/jwt/public.pem were created. The question is do I commit these files? If I don't, how do I use jwt on production? I will have different passphrases for different environments of course, but does that mean I can keep the public and private keys same across all environments?

Comment: I would recommend that you do not transfer these files, nor put them in your version management. Generate the key pair during the deployment and store them outside the deployment directory of Symfony.  With `lexik:jwt:generate-keypair --skip-if-exists` they will not be generated again during the next deployment.